# Is the very first TypeScript compiler written in JavaScript?

Tags: typescript

I checkout the second commit in [TypeScript Repo](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript) and find out there already a `tc.js`(renamed to tsc.js later) which is unlikely hand written.

Is the very first TypeScript compiler written in JavaScript?
Is the source code of the first tsc.js available somewhere?

Comment: The second commit adds snapshots which are most likely from internal development. It's unclear how they bootstrapped the compiler as we don't have that history. Most likely, the compiler was written in a dumbed-down version of Typescript and translated to Javascript with a crude version of a compiler, to the point the typescript compiler could compile itself. This is probably why the bin folder was included directly in the repository. After that, they use an LKG (last known good) approach for successive compiler development and builds - the compiler has (almost) always been self-hosting.

Comment: You would have to ask the initial development team for specifics on the history, if they're even able to comment on it without violating NDAs and the like.

Comment: The very first version of a compiler has to be written in an existing language. It is very likely that, in the case of tsc, was JavaScript. Considering that TypeScript is a superset of JavaScript makes it a logical decision. I believe the [answer in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39235612/how-is-typescript-100-0-written-in-typescript) should give you more info on the subject of compiler bootstrapping.